# total size of c:foreach list in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have trying to get the count of list (c:foreach loop in jsp) to access in the javascript of the same page. Any syntax to use using javascript or jquery

ideally i am looking at  - need to know the size of listvariable in javascript

Answer (score 0):

> > > count of list (c:foreach loop in jsp) to access in the javascript of the same page.

i think you mean you want to foreach on a collection contained in javascript variable ?

use a jstl var/scriptlet and get the value of the JS collection in that jstl var/scriplet object, and then iterate over the java object declared. Ideally you shall be putting the size of the JS collection in some variable and accessing that directly.

Comment: ideally i am looking at     <c:forEach items="${ListVariable}" var="name" varStatus="counter"> - need to know the size of listvariable in javascript

Comment: I think 

var size = <%= ListVariable.size() %> 

shall work.